# Connection refused error in client and server program

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a very simple `client` and `server` code:

**Server:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;

    server_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9734);
    server_len = sizeof(server_address);

    bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);
    listen(server_sockfd, 5);

    while ( 1 )
    {
        char ch;
        printf("server waiting\n");
        client_len = sizeof(client_address);
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
        read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
        ch += 4;
        write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
        close(client_sockfd);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int result;
    char ch = 'P';

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    address.sin_port = htons(9734);

    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if(result == −1)
    {
        perror("oops: client1");
        return 1;
    }

    write(sockfd, &ch, 1);
    read(sockfd, &ch, 1);
    printf("char from server = %c\n", ch);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Consider I have executed the `server` code in machine `A(10.18.17.26)`, and when I'm trying to execute the `client` in machine X I'm getting this error:

```
$ ./client 10.18.17.26
oops: client1: Connection refused
```

But I'm able to `ping` machine A from machine X and vice versa. Machine `A` and `X` were connected in a `intranet` network.

But if I run the `client` code on peer servers of machine `A` it is working fine and generating this output:

```
$ ./client 10.18.17.26
char from server = T
```

Hope I can get a solution here to overcome this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A successful `ping` to an IP address doesn't necessarily mean that a specific port (9734, in your case) is also available for incoming connections or a server is listening on that port. You should try with `telnet` e.g. `telnet <ip> <port>`.

Comment: That port might not be accessible from outside, you need to check if you need to do port forwarding for that

Comment: Looks like a firewall or router is blocking the traffic. Please check what kind of traffic is sent and returned using e.g. Wireshark. The "connection refused" message indicates that the traffic is actively blocked. This is not a programming problem at al.

Comment: Try to execute both server and client on the same machine to test your program works. If it does on the same machine but not on different machines, then you know it's a network issue.

Comment: Both  `server` and `client` working fine on same machine. Port 9734 is also available for connections. Seems to be issue with the firewall or router.